# Ruby, Mongodb, Anemone: web crawler with possible memory leak?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, memory-leaks, web-crawler, anemone

I began to learn about web crawlers recently and I built a sample crawler with Ruby, [Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/), and [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) for storage.  I'm testing the crawler on a massive public website with possibly billions of links.

The crawler.rb is indexing the correct information, although when I check the memory use in activity monitor it shows the memory constantly growing.  I have only run the crawler for about 6-7 hours and the memory is showing 1.38GB for mongod and 1.37GB for the Ruby process.  It seems to be growing about 100MB every hour or so.

It seems that I might have a memory leak?  Is their a more optimal way I can achieve the same crawl without the memory escalating out of control so that it can run longer?

```rb
# Sample web_crawler.rb with Anemone, Mongodb and Ruby.

require 'anemone'

# do not store the page's body.
module Anemone
  class Page
    def to_hash
      {'url' => @url.to_s,
       'links' => links.map(&:to_s),
       'code' => @code,
       'visited' => @visited,
       'depth' => @depth,
       'referer' => @referer.to_s,
       'fetched' => @fetched}
    end
    def self.from_hash(hash)
      page = self.new(URI(hash['url']))
      {'@links' => hash['links'].map { |link| URI(link) },
       '@code' => hash['code'].to_i,
       '@visited' => hash['visited'],
       '@depth' => hash['depth'].to_i,
       '@referer' => hash['referer'],
       '@fetched' => hash['fetched']
      }.each do |var, value|
        page.instance_variable_set(var, value)
      end
      page
    end
  end
end


Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/", :discard_page_bodies => true, :threads => 1, :obey_robots_txt => true, :user_agent => "Example - Web Crawler", :large_scale_crawl => true) do | anemone |
  anemone.storage = Anemone::Storage.MongoDB

  #only crawl pages that contain /example in url
  anemone.focus_crawl do |page|
    links = page.links.delete_if do |link|
      (link.to_s =~ /example/).nil?
    end
  end

  # only process pages in the /example directory
  anemone.on_pages_like(/example/) do | page |
    regex = /some type of regex/
    example = page.doc.css('#example_div').inner_html.gsub(regex,'') rescue next

    # Save to text file
    if !example.nil? and example != ""
      open('example.txt', 'a') { |f| f.puts "#{example}"}
    end
    page.discard_doc!
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you figure out the cause of the leak? If you think it was bug in Anemone, did you report it over on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/issues)?

Comment: Related issues mentioned on the Anemone issue tracker include: [memory leak?](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/issues/49), [memory leak or inefficient memory handling](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/issues/29), and [Fixes OutOfMemory error for large sites](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/pull/30)

Comment: I reported it around the same time as posting here on SO. I was able to crawl what my task required by adding the suggested fixes and it made my crawl last a lot longer, although tbh the ram usage was steadily growing, just not as fast as it was previously. I'm still not sure what causes the memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also having a problem with this, but I am using redis as a datastore.

this is my crawler:

```
require "rubygems"

require "anemone"

urls = File.open("urls.csv")
opts = {discard_page_bodies: true, skip_query_strings: true, depth_limit:2000, read_timeout: 10} 

File.open("results.csv", "a") do |result_file|

  while row = urls.gets

    row_ = row.strip.split(',')
    if row_[1].start_with?("http://")
      url = row_[1]
    else
      url = "http://#{row_[1]}"
    end 
    Anemone.crawl(url, options = opts) do |anemone|
      anemone.storage = Anemone::Storage.Redis
      puts "crawling #{url}"    
      anemone.on_every_page do |page| 

        next if page.body == nil 

        if page.body.downcase.include?("sometext")
          puts "found one at #{url}"     
          result_file.puts "#{row_[0]},#{row_[1]}"
          next

        end # end if 

      end # end on_every_page

    end # end crawl

  end # end while

  # we're done
  puts "We're done."

end # end File.open
```

I applied the patch from [here](https://github.com/wordtracker/anemone/commit/487601ba6e4012320da4983e38ba94011097e6c9) to my core.rb file in the anemone gem:

```
35       # Prevent page_queue from using excessive RAM. Can indirectly limit ra    te of crawling. You'll additionally want to use discard_page_bodies and/or a     non-memory 'storage' option
36       :max_page_queue_size => 100,
```

...

(The following used to be on line 155)

```
157       page_queue = SizedQueue.new(@opts[:max_page_queue_size])
```

and I have an hourly cron job doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
r.flushall()
```

to try and keep redis' memory usage down. I'm restarting a giant crawl now, so we'll see how it goes!

I'll report back with results...

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar and I think that maybe you are just creating loads of data.

You are not saving the body so that should help memory requirements.

The only other improvement I can think of is to use Redis instead of Mongo as I found it was much more scalable for Anemone's storage.

Check the size of the data you have in mongo - I found I was saving a huge number of rows.